# Braintree - Drop-in UI - Apple Pay - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, braintree, applepay

I am integrating Braintree Drop-in UI for credit card, paypal and apple pay payments.
I have followed the basic steps of credit card payments. Everything works fine in sandbox.

Now I am implementing apple pay.

I have completed its configuration as mentioned here, successfully : https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/configuration/ios/v4

This is how it looks in simulator as of now :

[image]

I have written the following code to implement the credit card payment:

```
import UIKit
import BraintreeDropIn
import Braintree

class DonationPaymentViewController: UIViewController {

let toKinizationKey = "my_tokenization_key"
@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func sendRequestPaymentToServer(nonce: String, amount: String) {
    let paymentURL = URL(string: "my_api_url")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: paymentURL)
    print("paymentMethodNonce=\(nonce)&amount=\(amount)")
    //request.httpBody = "paymentMethodNonce=\(nonce)&amount=\(amount)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let token = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Token") as! String

    let params = ["paymentMethodNonce":"\(nonce)", "amount":amount] as [String : Any]

    let prettyPrinted:Bool = false
    let options = prettyPrinted ?
        JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted : JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: options)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] (data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard let data = data else {
            self?.show(message: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }

        guard let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any], let success = result?["success"] as? Bool, success == true else {
            self?.show(message: "Transaction failed. Please try again.")
            return
        }

        self?.show(message: "Successfully charged. Thanks So Much :)")
        }.resume()
}

@IBAction func pay(_ sender: Any) {
    let request =  BTDropInRequest()
    let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: toKinizationKey, request: request)
    { [unowned self] (controller, result, error) in

        if let error = error {
            self.show(message: error.localizedDescription)


        } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
            self.show(message: "Transaction Cancelled")

        } else if let nonce = result?.paymentMethod?.nonce, let amount = self.amountTextField.text {
            self.sendRequestPaymentToServer(nonce: nonce, amount: amount)
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func show(message: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: message, message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

}
```

I need help in coding for apple pay. Braintree docs do not provide proper info on `Braintree Drop-in UI for Apple Pay using Swift 3`. This is the link I am supposed to follow : https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/client-side/ios/v4
But it doesn't seem to be for Drop-in UI. Any help on Braintree drop-in UI for apple pay and paypal would be highly appreciated.

Comment: after generating client token and all how to identify which option is clicked either paypal or creditcard please help me for onActivityResult how for creditcard or paypal please help me

Comment: @Harsha I have put this line `switch result.paymentOptionType {
            case .applePay ,.payPal,.masterCard,.discover,.visa:` You can figure out by having separate cases for each

Comment: Sure thank you,I got it. Paytype VISA                        
DropInResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT);
        PaymentMethodNonce nonce = result.getPaymentMethodNonce();                                 
                    HashMap paramsHash = new HashMap<>();
                    paramsHash.put("amount", "2");
                    paramsHash.put("nonce", nonce.getNonce());
                    sendPayments(paramsHash);       calling sendPayment my server methode with amount and nonce as parameters.                                
 If paytype-Paypal

Comment: Thank you if paytype paypal how can i call server checkout api.for creditcard am passing amount and nonce.working fine.problem with paypal please provide some code in paypal selection please for android am wasting too much time for this

Comment: @Harsha For android?

Comment: Yes am asking about Android Paypal Option clicked what should i do.If am doing same as Creditcard showing error after checkout api calling payment_methode_nonce_more than once error message please help me

Comment: @Mamta i am also using BTDropInRequest but the apple pay option is not showing in dorpin UI. can you please help me.

Comment: @Mamta, From where you have create tokenization key for sandbox. 
 https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/ is not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check code below i write comment as i can , when user select apple pay you have to configure paymentRequest    `let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()`
then handle `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate` to Get `nonce`

```
func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String) {
    let request =  BTDropInRequest()
    request.applePayDisabled = false // Make sure that  applePayDisabled i sfalse

    let dropIn = BTDropInController.init(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request) { (controller, result, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("ERROR")
        } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
            print("CANCELLED")

        } else if let result = result{

            switch result.paymentOptionType {
            case .applePay ,.payPal,.masterCard,.discover,.visa:
                 // Here Result success  check paymentMethod not nil if nil then user select applePay
                if let paymentMethod = result.paymentMethod{
                    //paymentMethod.nonce  You can use  nonce now
             controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }else{

                    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

                        self.braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey)

                        // call apple pay
                        let paymentRequest = self.paymentRequest()

                        // Example: Promote PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController to optional so that we can verify
                        // that our paymentRequest is valid. Otherwise, an invalid paymentRequest would crash our app.

                        if let vc = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
                            as PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?
                        {
                            vc.delegate = self
                            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        } else {
                            print("Error: Payment request is invalid.")
                        }

                    })




                }
            default:
                print("error")
                controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
            // result.paymentOptionType
            // result.paymentMethod
            // result.paymentIcon
            // result.paymentDescription
        }


    }

    self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



extension ViewController : PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate{

    func paymentRequest() -> PKPaymentRequest {
        let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
        paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.Demo.example";
        paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.amex, PKPaymentNetwork.visa, PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard];
        paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS;
        paymentRequest.countryCode = "US"; // e.g. US
        paymentRequest.currencyCode = "USD"; // e.g. USD
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Dish", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(MyOrdersViewController.totalOrderPrice)")),

        ]
        return paymentRequest
    }





    public func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Swift.Void){

        // Example: Tokenize the Apple Pay payment
        let applePayClient = BTApplePayClient(apiClient: braintreeClient!)
        applePayClient.tokenizeApplePay(payment) {
            (tokenizedApplePayPayment, error) in
            guard let tokenizedApplePayPayment = tokenizedApplePayPayment else {
                // Tokenization failed. Check `error` for the cause of the failure.

                // Indicate failure via completion callback.
                completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.failure)

                return
            }

            // Received a tokenized Apple Pay payment from Braintree.
            // If applicable, address information is accessible in `payment`.

            // Send the nonce to your server for processing.
            print("nonce = \(tokenizedApplePayPayment.nonce)")

            //  self.postNonceToServer(paymentMethodNonce: tokenizedApplePayPayment.nonce)
            // Then indicate success or failure via the completion callback, e.g.
            completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.success)
        }
    }

    func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

Comment: I am getting this warning in my console. `Warning: Attempt to present <PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController: 0x7fa9baf4e540>  on <Project.DonationPaymentViewController: 0x7fa9baf49a20> which is already presenting (null)`. I cannot see any pop up.

Comment: add in app delegate  `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`